# A foreign key constraint fails when insert to table with gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

When I try to insert to a table with gorm which has one to many relationship, I get this error:

```
Error 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`Todo`.`todos`, CONSTRAINT `fk_users_todo_list` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE)....
```

These are my models:

```
type Base struct {
    ID        uint `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
    DeletedAt *time.Time `gorm:"index"`
}

type User struct {
    Base
    FirstName string           `form:"first_name" gorm:"type:varchar(20)"`
    LastName  string           `form:"last_name" gorm:"type:varchar(20)"`
    UserName  string           `form:"user_name" gorm:"unique;type:varchar(20)"`
    Email     string           `form:"email" gorm:"type:varchar(100)"`
    Password  string           `form:"password" gorm:"type:varchar(30)"`
    Gender    types.UserGender `form:"gender" gorm:"type:smallint"`
    TodoList  []Todo           `gorm:"foreignKey:FkID;constraint:onDelete:SET NULL,onUpdate:CASCADE" json:"omitempty"`
}

type Todo struct {
    Base
    Name        string
    Description string
    Status      types.TaskStatus
    FkID        uint
}
```

And this is the function that I wrote:

```
func (d *DB) AddTODO(todo *models.Todo, userName string) error {
    user := &models.User{UserName: userName}
    err := d.db.Model(&user).Where("user_name = ?", userName).Association("TodoList").
        Append([]models.Todo{*todo})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

I'm using MariaDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It want `user` from gorm result. Change your method maybe like this:

```golang
// arg user is from gorm result somewhere
func (d *DB) AddTODO(user *models.User, todo *models.Todo) error {
    return d.db.Model(user).Association("TodoList").Append([]models.Todo{*todo})
}
```

Comment: i created a user and it's okay when i try to access it with mysql or goland query console or with gorm,
and when i write query like you it throw this error: ```WHERE conditions required
[0.364ms] [rows:0] UPDATE `users` SET `updated_at`='2022-03-03 12:27:37.347'
```

Comment: I think it want a `user` from gorm result, like this example, https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/jinzhu/gorm/-/blob/association_test.go?L601 see line 601 and line 620

Comment: thnak you !
i tried to get user's full info and then create a todo and it's working!

Comment: OK, I'll edit my answer above

Comment: Btw you forgot to get the `Error`, see my edited answer.

Comment: `Association("TodoList").Append([]models.Todo{*todo}) ` return error by default
see this [link](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/blob/4e523499d191d02e032b126774efd26daa8697a8/association.go#L50)

Comment: OK, maybe I see different version of gorm.

Answer (score 0):

`TodoList` lack references keyword. It should be like this.

```golang
type User struct {
    Base
    FirstName string           `form:"first_name" gorm:"type:varchar(20)"`
    LastName  string           `form:"last_name" gorm:"type:varchar(20)"`
    UserName  string           `form:"user_name" gorm:"unique;type:varchar(20)"`
    Email     string           `form:"email" gorm:"type:varchar(100)"`
    Password  string           `form:"password" gorm:"type:varchar(30)"`
    Gender    types.UserGender `form:"gender" gorm:"type:smallint"`
    TodoList  []Todo           `gorm:"foreignKey:FkID;references:ID;constraint:onDelete:SET NULL,onUpdate:CASCADE" json:"omitempty"`
}
```

Comment: i tried it and its same
```Error 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`Todo`.`todos`, CONSTRAINT `fk_users_todo_list` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE)
[1.267ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO `todos` (`created_at`,`updated_at`,`deleted_at`,`name`,`description`,`status`,`fk_id`) VALUES ('2022-03-03 12:17:38.649','2022-03-03 12:17:38.649',NULL,'my first todo','Test description','2',0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `fk_id`=VALUES(`fk_id`)
```
this is the full error.